# How do I get the updated objects

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, local-storage

Here is the problem, I do an Ajax request on a file which represents an array of objects, then I update each objects one by one in the array, then I store the array in localStorage with a JSON.stringify.
After doing all that, in the console I get the array with updated objects but when I store the array, it's the old array that is stored.

Here is my code.

```
var relaisList;
function updateRelaisList(){
    $.ajax({
        "dataType":"json",
        "url": "assets/json/relaisList.json"
    })
    .done(function(response){
        console.log("ajax updatedRelaisList SUCCESS");
        //add lat and lng for all relaisList objects
        for(var i = 0, c = response.length; i < c; i++){
            addLatLng(response[i]);
        }
        //store the updated array in the localStorage
        console.log("below is the updatedRelaisList>>>")
        console.log(response)
        relaisList = response
        window.localStorage.setItem("foo", JSON.stringify(relaisList))  


    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log("ajax updateRelaisList FAIL");
    })
}

function addLatLng(obj){
    var fullAddress = obj.name + "," + obj.address + "," + obj.zip;
    $.ajax({
        "dataType":"json",
        "url": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + fullAddress + "&key=AIzaSyB67tGq_pe2p6ma3QVlkciQaL4-rKIC_UE"
    })
    .done(function(response){
        console.log("ajax addLatLng SUCCESS");
        //update the object adding 2 properties lat and lng
        obj.lat = response.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        obj.lng = response.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        // console.log(obj)
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log("ajax addLatLng FAIL");
    })  
}
```

Feel free to ask me more details

Comment: Just a quick guess, but my thought is, because you're using a pre-written method that also calls ajax to add information to your object, but then storing locally right after, your local storage is being updated faster than the return ajax call.

Comment: Ajax request takes some time to complete, and is asynchronous as well. so check if your other code where you are trying to access that variable is not executing before it get stored.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try with below modified code. This code will wait for all Ajax responses and will upload data to local storage only when all lat/long gets fetched from google maps:

```
var relaisList;
function updateRelaisList(){
    $.ajax({
        "dataType":"json",
        "url": "assets/json/relaisList.json"
    })
    .done(function(response){
        console.log("ajax updatedRelaisList SUCCESS");
        addLatLng(response);
     })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log("ajax updateRelaisList FAIL");
    })
}

function addLatLng(response){
    var updatedResponse =[];
    //add lat and lng for all relaisList objects
    for(var i = 0, c = response.length; i < c; i++){
        obj = response[i];
        var fullAddress = obj.name + "," + obj.address + "," + obj.zip;
        $.ajax({
            "dataType":"json",
            "url": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + fullAddress + "&key=AIzaSyB67tGq_pe2p6ma3QVlkciQaL4-rKIC_UE"
        })
        .done(function(response_inner){
            console.log("ajax addLatLng SUCCESS");
            //update the object adding 2 properties lat and lng
            obj.lat = response_inner.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            obj.lng = response_inner.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            updatedResponse.push(obj);
            if(updatedResponse.length == response.length){
                //store the updated array in the localStorage
                console.log("below is the updatedRelaisList>>>")
                console.log(response)
                relaisList = response
                window.localStorage.setItem("foo", JSON.stringify(relaisList));  
            }
        })
        .fail(function(){
            console.log("ajax addLatLng FAIL");
        })  

    }


}
```